# Install pybrain in ubuntu 16.04 "ImportError: No module named pybrain.structure"

Tags: python, pybrain

I'm getting that error:

`ImportError: No module named pybrain.structure`

When executing:

`from pybrain.pybrain.structure import FeedForwardNetwork`

From the pybrain tutorial.

I installed pybrain running:

`sudo python setup.py install`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved replacing `pybrain.pybrain` by `pybrain`.